# Получение нужного цвета суммированием цветов с прозрачностью

Tags: цвета, opacity, rgb

Возникла вот какая задача. Пусть есть исходный цвет `#xxxxxx`. Нужно получить другой цвет `#yyyyyy`, где значения первого цвета и второго - произвольные. Для получения второго цвета из первого можно суммировать другие цвета, применяя при это прозрачность накладываемого цвета (или цветов).

Простой пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Очень важны следующие аспекты:**

1. Нельзя накладывать цвет вообще без прозрачности - задача теряет свой смысл
2. Суммируемая прозрачность всех накладываемых цветов должна быть максимальной по возможности
3. Каждый отдельный накладываемый цвет так же должен по максимуму быть прозрачным

Понимаю, что формулы тут может и не быть. Но как такое решить итерациями хотя бы?

**P.S.** Речь конечно же о решаемых вариантах. Мы не будем искать получение конечного цвета типа `#ffffff`, ибо это нерешаемо в данной постановке вопроса.